# Why is my form text input value POSTing as list?

Tags: html, django, http

My form field value is being received as a list and I can't figure out why.

I need it to just be a string.

form

```
<form id="design-brief-3" name="design-brief-3" data-name="Design Brief 3" class="contact-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'project-design' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-field-container">
    <label for="business_slogan" class="form-field-label">Business Slogan/Tagline/Mission Statement</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="business_slogan" data-name="business_slogan" placeholder="If we say 'Just Do It' you know what we mean." id="business_slogan" required=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-container">
    <label for="essential_content" class="form-field-label">Essential Content</label>
    <textarea required="" maxlength="5000" id="essential_content" name="essential_content" data-name="essential_content" placeholder="Please include any content you have, it can be as long as you want." class="form-field message w-input"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field-container">
    <label for="logo" class="form-field-label">If you have a logo, upload it here.</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-field w-input" name="logo" data-name="logo" id="Logo"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-field-container">
   <label for="#id_file" class="form-field-label">Additional files, such as page copies & additional images, you can upload multiple.</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-field w-input" name="#id_file" data-name="#id_file" id="#id_file" multiple="multiple"/>
```

View:

```
def projectdesign(request):

   if request.POST:
       print(request.POST)

   return render(request, 'users/projectdesign.html', context)
```

Output:

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['9p3NTDraxyssQZNdavUSrUaJaT1rQTIImn5rMnjm1F'], 'business_slogan': ['Just do it'], 'essential_content': ['sdsdsad'], 'logo': [''], '#id_file': ['']}>`

Comment: You have many form field values, not just one - and every form field value in your output is a string - for example the input with the id 'essential_content' has the value 'sdsdsad' - a string...

Comment: They are lists because it's allowable to have two (or more) input fields with the same name, and in that case the list would have two (or more) values -- one for each field of the same name.  Even when you have only one field of the same name, the value is presented as a list for consistency.